# Django can't extend to a template in another app

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is the structure of the project right now.

```
webbshop
  templates
    webbshop
      base.html
      settings.py
home
  templates
    home
      index.html
```

In my "webbshop" settings which is the "main" app where i got my settings.

But when I try to extend the base.html with index.html I get this error:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: webbshop/base.html"

On the page it shows this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUQbd.png

It appears that it does not go and look for the template in the webbshop app. I searched around and that should work.

This is my index.html

```
{% extends 'webbshop/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
hey
{% endblock %}
```

These are the installed apps that i got in the webbshop app.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
]
```

**SOLVED IT!
Solution:**

Even though i had the settings.py file in the webbshop app i still had to add "webbshop" as an installed app. Otherwise it would not recognize the templates in that app.

Comment: Is `webbshop` also in INSTALLED_APPS? There's no such thing as a "main app" in Django.

Comment: Even though the settings is in the webbshop app do i need to add webbshop as an installed_app?

Comment: Yes; nothing makes `webbshop` an app, if it's not in `INSTALLED_APPS`. (You're probably mixing projects and apps.) If you add it there, you won't need to add file system template directories as that answer implies.

Comment: Note, none of `settings.py` files are supposed to be located in templates folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my comment an answer you can accept:

There's no such concept as "main app" in Django; if `webbshop` happens to contain `webbshop/settings.py`, it probably is the Django project module, but it's not automagically an app.

You'll need to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` (even if it doesn't provide views, urls, models, ...) for the default template lookup mechanism to find templates under `webbshop/templates`.

Comment: Yeah! I can't remember how i figured it out but i got it to work with this solution :)
I thought the app it created automatically was the "main app" in the project so i figured it would look there by default. Still learning Django and it's proven to be very powerful so far in what i am capable of doing in a short period of time even as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok gotcha, what you need is to make these changes in your settings.py :
below BASE_DIR line add this line:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

and add this new variable 'TEMPLATE_DIR' under TEMPLATES under DIRS as:

TEMPLATES  -> 'DIRS' :[TEMPLATE_DIR],

Thanks.

Comment: My project name is webbshop
I've édited the main post.

Comment: Ohk gotcha, what you need is type this in your settings.py under BASE_DIR line: TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') and edit TEMPLATES variable -> 'DIRS' :[TEMPLATE_DIR], 

See if this helps, and if not show the whole settings.py file